I'm having trouble finding the time it takes to execute code
/**
 * How to determine whether a given integer is prime number Compare time
 */

 public class PrimeAlgorithmComparison2 {
    /**
    * Is the given natural number prime number?
    * First method
    * @paramn A given natural number
    * @return If it's a prime number, it's true, otherwise it's false.
     */
    public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
  
        boolean isPrime = true;

        for (long i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
    
    /**
     * Is the given natural number prime number?
     * Second method
     * @param n A given natural number
     * @return If it's a prime number, it's true, otherwise it's false.
     */
    public static boolean isPrime2(long n) {
  

        boolean isPrime = true;

        for (long i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        return isPrime;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long n = 3033333343L;

        long startTime;
        long endTime;

      
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean result1 = isPrime(n);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("First method, calculation time: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
        System.out.println(n + " is a prime number: " + result1);
     

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean result2 = isPrime2(n);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Second method, calculation time: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
        System.out.println(n + " is a prime number: " + result2);
    }
}

When I ran it myself, the results were as follows
First method, calculation time: 6907ms
3033333343 is a prime number: true
Second method, calculation time: 0ms
3033333343 is a prime number: true

However, compared to the first method, the second method was output as 0, whether it was because the second method ran much faster or if the calculation was wrong. There was no problem when I printed the start time and end time respectively. It would be easy to calculate using nanoTime(), but the original method doesn't seem wrong. I wonder why 0 comes out if I find the difference between end time and start time. I set the data type to long, but there seems to be no problem with the formula. Is there a reason why I don't know?
I know a similar question is already on this site but I want to know why 0 appears. Also, I don't want to change System.currentTimeMillis();

Microbenchmarking in java has various pitfalls. Some reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/21105992

One important point in Java is not to use System.currentTimeMillis(), it's not really accurate enough for benchmark timing.  (Whether you want to change it or not is immaterial, don't use it.)

It certainly seems possible that changing the loop to only use the square root of n has resulted in a large time savings.  Can you verify the output with different numbers?

What number should I use?

By some unscientific fiddling with your code (e.g. running the function 1e8 times with volatile n to prevent the jvm from optimizing it away), isPrime2 appears to be about 2 billion times faster than isPrime for this input. So the measurement is likely correct and just lacks resolution to show any useful number for isPrime2.

The algorithm is to

measure1
heavylift
measure2
do something with measure2 - measure1

You did just that and in general you should trust your results, even though currentTimeMillis is not too accurate and it is recommended to use nanoTime instead. But, if you have doubts of whether your measurement works, then add something like java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3) in-between the measurements. If the measurements end up having the difference you have imposed upon them, then the operation was just unbelievably quick.
